# Changing external workbook Links in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a report spreadsheet that I use monthly. It uses data from multiple workbooks that are linked to it. To update the report every month, I copy the tab from the last month and update the links. I use the Find & Replace method to update the values (ex. Find "Jul" and replace with "Aug").

The main problem I have is when I do this, the windows explorer box pops up asking me which file to use for each link I have. There are ~100 cells that use linked data so I end up having to choose the current month data file for every linked cell. I can't seem to get around this. Any thoughts?

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Excel is doing what it is supposed (by asking for the file) to because changing its source data is confusing it.

Without knowing what version of Excel you are using or seeing how you have your sheet setup, and if I understand what you are trying to accomplish, there may be two solutions for you:

***Option One***

Turn off automatic calculations or link updates in Excel options / Data Connections options, depending how you set it up, so it wont update the links while you are modifying them. Then manually update the links after you are done editing them.

***Option Two***

Rather than paste data and modify the links in your report, try creating a standard source file which your report looks to for its data. Then paste your monthly data into it rather than into the sheet you are using for your report.

Now create a query to populate the data for your report from the source file. This will then look to the data without having to update the links each month, plus the query will give you the ability to filter data to your liking.